# Jpa repository query not working

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a select query which looks like this .

```
Select column_name_1, column_name_2 
from table_name 
where column_name_1= values and column_name_2 in ( <thisList> )
```

This list has 200 000 records.

I wrote `findByC1AndC2In(:thisList)` here.  It is working for list with a small number of records, but fails for huge data.

Comment: findByC1AndC2In(List thisList) using sql in operator, depending on the database engine you are using, there can be limits on the length of an instruction

Comment: Are you using `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` interfaces? If so `@Query` could solve this very nicely. Also is there a relationship there? In the `@Entity` class is there something like `@OneToMany` or something like that on that table? If so we can map it to a DTO and let spring data do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a max result like this:

```
String sql = "Select column_name_1, column_name_2 from table_name where column_name_1= values and column_name_2";

Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
query.setMaxResults(numberOfRecords);
List result = query.getResultList();
```